# report print dropdown odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have to add an item in print menu from purchase order tree view in odoo 8.
i am unable to find where is current Purchase Order reports added in print menu. i researched and found there is a tag  from below:

```
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-add-an-item-to-the-more-drop-down-list-in-sales-module-61833
```

also tried below, but i am getting qweb error :

```
<act_window name="Print Receiving Wkst"
        res_model = "purchase.order"
        src_model = "purchase.order"
        key = "action"
        key2="client_print_multi"
        value="ir.actions.act_window,action_report_print_receivePO"
        id="act_print_recevg_wkst"
    />
```

my custom report is in "test" module with id "action_report_print_receivePO"

I am getting error for value tag i think.

Basically i have to add new entry in print menu from purchase order tree view. so that when ever it is clicked custom report is printed. moreover if more than one PO selected, it will create PDF of all the POs

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go through the stress of creating an `action` and then adding a new item to the "More dropdown". Odoo already provides a way for you do this. just set `menu = True` when you're registering your report and a Print option would appear in the "More dropdown" that prints your report.

```
<report
    id="purchase_order_report"
    string="Purchase order"
    model="purchase.order"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    file="purchase.order.file"
    name="purchase.order.report"
    menu="True"
/>
```

For more information on what the other parameters mean please refer to the
[docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html)

Comment: Hi danidee, Thanks for reply, i will try and get back to you. I have question, if i need to show the report in two model, eg. ( stock.picking and purchase.order), moreover how can i get report from stock.picking to show in purchase.order view.

Comment: For that you'd have to go with a similar approach to what you tried to do earlier (since the report is from a different model)....but instead of trying to add an option to the `More dropdown` you can easily use a button that calls a method in your custom class which prints the report....it's much easier than trying to add an item to the `More dropdown`

Comment: Thanks danidee very much

Answer (score 1):

just in case you might want to generate reports of a different types not fully supported by Odoo, such as **py3o** you'll definitely need to create a [report action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/actions.html#report-actions-ir-actions-report) as defined in the official doc. For example:

```
<record id="account.account_invoices" model="ir.actions.report">
  <field name="report_type">py3o</field>
  <field name="py3o_filetype">odt</field>
  <field name="module">my_custom_module_base</field>
  <field name="py3o_template_fallback">report/account_invoice.odt</field>
</record>
```

However for your action to appear in the **Print dropdown list**, you must add two more fields to the record

```
<field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_my_custom_module_base"/>
<field name="binding_type">report</field>
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future!!
NB: Here I'm using the [py3o reporting engine](https://pypi.org/project/odoo12-addon-report-py3o/). Check it out as an alternative to the native qweb engine.